# Github Reusable Workflow: How to use the workflow of the last commit (or branch head) instead hardcoding a branch name / release version?

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm setting up a reusable workflow using GitHub actions: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/reusing-workflows

Since the callee workflow and caller workflow are both in the same repo, I want to reference the latest commit of the called workflow inside my calling workflow's `uses` statement.

Example:

```
uses: owner/repo/.github/workflows/called-workflow.yml@${{GITHUB_SHA}}
```

That `${{GITHUB_SHA}}` doesn't get interpolated, so I get the following error:

```
Invalid workflow file : .github/workflows/calling-workflow.yml#L1
handling usage of workflow "owner/repo/.github/workflows/called-workflow.yml@${{GITHUB_SHA}}": can't obtain workflow file: reference to workflow should be either a valid branch, tag, or commit
```

How can I set the `ref` to the latest commit when calling a workflow within a workflow?

Comment: For those who are wondering, I'm hard-coding the branch name as the ref for the time being. It's not ideal, as I'd like to reference the latest commit that triggered the workflow, but it does work: `uses: owner/repo/.github/workflows/called-workflow.yml@main`

Comment: I am stuck on this as well, has anyone solved this?

Comment: Not me, I'm still using the workaround

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reuse a GitHub Actions workflow from the branch I'm currently working on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69532525/how-can-i-reuse-a-github-actions-workflow-from-the-branch-im-currently-working)

Comment: @TWiStErRob Looks like the same question. You propose a neat workaround. I commented on it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## This is now possible

As of February 2022.

First in January: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-01-25-github-actions-reusable-workflows-can-be-referenced-locally/

Up until today-ish though (2022-Feb-10), there was a bug that prevented it from working on `pull_request` events; that has now been fixed:
https://github.community/t/ref-head-in-reusable-workflows/203690/74?u=briantist

Example usage:

```yaml
jobs:
  call-workflow-in-local-repo:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/workflow-2.yml
```

Note: The callee and caller workflow must be in the same repository. (See: [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#calling-a-reusable-workflow) for more info)

Comment: Now all we need is a way to reference actions from the same repo/commit as the shared workflow...

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by reference actions from the same repo/commit?

Comment: @JohnnyOshika sure, consider a repository that contains both actions and reusable workflows. You want the workflows to use the actions. But you cannot reference the actions using the typical local syntax (after checkout) (`uses: ./.github/actions/name`), because the shared workflow runs in the context of the consumer, so has no info on which repo, but especially which ref, to checkout. There is no way to get the ref of the shared workflow that's being invoked. For specifics in a project I run: https://github.com/ansible-community/github-docs-build/issues/4

Comment: Thanks for this! I found it in the docs, but wanted to double check this info was also on SO. Link here -> https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#calling-a-reusable-workflow "If you use the second syntax option (without {owner}/{repo} and @{ref}) the called workflow is from the same commit as the caller workflow."

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatelly, it's not possible to use [expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#about-expressions) with `uses` now.

One possible workaround (that I used for myself) is to push reusable workflow(s) to one of the stable branches (`main`/`master`/`develop`/etc.) and use SHA as a `ref`.

Additional benefit here is that using SHA is actually the recommended way described [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_iduses).

Answer (score 1):

Update: This answer is out of date as they now support it, please disregard this answer...

It's currently not supported. It looks like they are actively working on a solution for this though. https://github.community/t/ref-head-in-reusable-workflows/203690/15

My current workaround is to put what was in a reusable workflow into a local custom action instead. It's less than optimal when you have multiple jobs that are interconnected though. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action

Comment: Folks could also maybe head into that github community support post and give that a like. Maybe it'll encourage GitHub to put more resources into this feature... :D