# How can I reuse a GitHub Actions workflow from the branch I'm currently working on?

Tags: github-actions

I'd like to abstract some of my GitHub Actions with a [reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/reusing-workflows).

In order to do this, I need to call my newly defined callable workflow in the format `{owner}/{repo}/{path}/{filename}@{ref}`

e.g. (from the docs)

```
jobs:
  call-workflow-1:
    uses: octo-org/this-repo/.github/workflows/workflow-1.yml@172239021f7ba04fe7327647b213799853a9eb89
  call-workflow-2:
    uses: octo-org/another-repo/.github/workflows/workflow-2.yml@v1
```

However, in practice, I'm working on my branch, `some-branch-name`, where I'm working on my `workflow-1.yml` file and I'd like to be able to run my actions as defined in my current branch, Given

> `{ref} can be a SHA, a release tag, or a branch name.

It seems like I'd need to use

```
jobs:
  call-workflow-1:
    uses: octo-org/this-repo/.github/workflows/workflow-1.yml@some-branch-name
```

But, I'd like this to work for any branch, so

```
jobs:
  call-workflow-1:
    uses: octo-org/this-repo/.github/workflows/workflow-1.yml@${{ github.ref }}
```

But, it turns out this isn't possible as expressions [can't be used](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#context-availability) in the `uses` attributes.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It's as you said. It can't be done at the moment as Github Actions doesn't support expressions with `uses` attributes. There is no workaround (yet?) because the workflow interpreter (that also check the workflow syntax you push the workflow to the repository) can't get the value from the expression at that moment. It could maybe work if the workflow was recognize by the interpreter, but it doesn't event appear on the Actions tab as it's considered invalid.

Comment: For the moment, you can only use `tag`, `branch ref` or `commit hash` after the `@` symbol, the same way you use any action. (Someone else had the same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69500491/github-reusable-workflow-use-latest-commit)

Comment: @GuiFalourd you should make that an answer so you can be properly awarded. Even if what OP requests can't be done, I'm sure other people will look for the same question and appreciate your knowledge that it currently isn't possible and why.

Comment: @croakPedlar Thanks for the feedback. I'll add it as you suggested 

Comment: I've added a status update and a potential workaround over here if this helps out at all. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70571455/162830

Comment: This was fixed only a week ago. It is now possible to reference the reusable workflow with a relative path: `uses: ./.github/workflows/...`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71067823/6813271 and the links there.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**This is now supported as of 25 January 2022.**

https://github.blog/changelog/2022-01-25-github-actions-reusable-workflows-can-be-referenced-locally/

Example usage from blog:

```yaml
jobs:
  call-workflow-in-local-repo:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/workflow-2.yml
```

And a real life example from [my opened issue](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/issues/932):
https://github.com/TWiStErRob/net.twisterrob.healthcheck/pull/28

*Note: With this `./` syntax the reusable workflow definition (`.yml` file) and the usage (`uses` from a job) must be in the same repository. See: [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#calling-a-reusable-workflow) for more info.*

Comment: @Joshua this should be the approved answer now

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69500491/github-reusable-workflow-use-latest-commit

Comment: @MarkHan "The callee and caller workflow must be in the same repository" is kind-of implicit, because the question was "from the same branch", and you can't have the same branch between multiple repositories as per git's definition of "branch".

Comment: @TWiStErRob Extra clarity isn't necessarily a bad thing here; even if it seems obvious to some, it might not be obvious to others.

Comment: The question was about calling an action in a known branch/etc. This answer is about calling a reusable workflow in a known branch/etc.

Comment: @LeeMeador Calling local actions with the `./` syntax was supported before calling local reusable workflows. Notice that the question only contains `uses:` inside `jobs:`, not steps.

Answer (score 14):

*EDIT: **[This is now supported as of 25 January 2022](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-01-25-github-actions-reusable-workflows-can-be-referenced-locally/)***

*(check [**TWiStErRob**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72498960/253468) for more details).*

---

***Previous answer (before 2022 update)***

It's as you said: It can't be done at the moment as Github Actions doesn't support expressions with `uses` attributes.

**There is no workaround** (yet?) because the workflow interpreter (that also checks the workflow syntax when you push the workflow to the repository) can't get the value from the expression at that moment.

It could maybe work if the workflow was recognized by the interpreter, but it doesn't event appear on the `Actions` tab as it's considered invalid.

For the moment, you can only use `tag`, `branch ref` or `commit hash` after the `@` symbol, the same way you use any action.

[*Note that someone else had the same issue here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69500491/github-reusable-workflow-use-latest-commit)

Comment: Could https://stackoverflow.com/a/69785356/253468 work as a workaround?

Comment: It could be worth testing to see if it works as expected. I'll check it! Thanks for sharing 

Comment: "Yet" has come: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72498960/253468

Comment: @TWiStErRob has the updated and correct answer below

Answer (score 4):

**Update: DO NOT USE THIS, see [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72498960/253468).**

---

A really hacky (and untested) way to **workaround** this.

Based on the fact that a workflow can contain multiple jobs, and assuming a low-churn PR environment one could set up something like this:

```yaml
jobs:
  tag-my-workflow:
    steps:
      - name: git tag ${{ github.ref }} as "current-branch"
        uses: see for example https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-move-a-git-tag-using-github-actions-e23a523eb325

  call-workflow:
    needs: tag-my-workflow
    uses: my/repo/.github/workflows/called.yml@current-branch
```

Comment: What happens if multiple workflows (triggered by different commits) run in parallel?

Comment: Same workflow runs on different commits... that's where my "assuming a low-churn PR environment" comes to play. :) In the end the window for conflict is a few seconds, because tagging should be really quick and once call-workflow started I think the tag can move.

Comment: That makes sense. A neat workaround, but I hope GitHub adds a proper solution soon.

Comment: Note for future readers: if you encounter this, please upvote the question and let GitHub know about your problem. Without feedback it's unlikely to get a fix.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is not working as expected. Workflow loaded and interpreted before any operation. It means that you will always take previous "current-branch" and not new one that was "prepared" in setup job.

Comment: @solikhver even if it's `needs:`? What if one workflow triggers another one?

Answer (score 3):

I used the workflow-dispatch github action described [here](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/workflow-dispatch) to successfully trigger a workflow B in the same repo (note that you need to set up a personal access token secret and include `ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}` to refer to the current branch).

But unfortunately workflow A continues once workflow B has been triggered, rather than waiting around to see if workflow B succeeds. As suggested in [this thread](https://github.com/benc-uk/workflow-dispatch/issues/2) it might be possible to use another [github action](https://github.com/lewagon/wait-on-check-action) to make workflow A wait for workflow B to successfully finish, but that seemed like overkill for me... maybe this'll be useful to someone else though. Fingers crossed it gets supported instead :D

Answer (score 1):

We all know that this is untenable and must have a solution in the long term: You're going to want to establish a common pipeline and have perhaps hundreds of repos calling the same workflow. Having to commit to 'main' on your reusable workflow to test it could break every pipeline that depends on it. So GHA will pick up this functionality soon enough simply because it has to.
**Workaround:** What about forking instead of branching for now?  You can develop and test on the fork and submit a PR when it works.